# Test passes for expect(onAgree).not.toHaveBeenCalled() AND ALSO for expect(onAgree).toHaveBeenCalled()! How?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm not very experience with jest async testing. This have this test which passes. The `onAgree` function gets called, `'on agree called'` is getting printed out. Despite that `expect(onAgree).not.toHaveBeenCalled();` test passes. If I change it to `expect(onAgree).toHaveBeenCalled()`; it passes too, which I have no idea why. It is very strange to me,  how could it pass both ways? `expect(onAgree).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)` and `expect(onAgree).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` also passes. `expect(onAgree).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)` does not pass:  Expected number of calls: 2, Received number of calls: 1. How does it pass for 0? I think it's jest/async related does not have to do with formik/my Checkbox component.

```
const onAgree = jest.fn(() => { console.log('on agree called') });

const StandaloneCheckbox = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Checkbox />
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider >
)

const FormikCheckbox = () => {
    const validator = {
        useragreement: ({ useragreement: userAgrees }) => {
            console.log('validator: ', userAgrees)
            return userAgrees ? undefined : 'You must agree to submit!'
        }
    }

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        useragreement: true
                    }}
                    validate={async values => {
                        return await formikValidator(validator, values)
                    }}
                    onSubmit={onAgree}
                >
                    <Form>
                        <Field name="useragreement" component={Checkbox} />
                        <button type="submit">Agree</button>
                    </Form>
                </Formik>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider >
    )
}


describe('Checkbox should work with formik.', () => {
    test('Submit function should be called only if checkbox is checked.', async () => {
        const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(
            <FormikCheckbox />
        )

        const checkSignContainer = getByTestId('checksign-container');
        const agreeButton = getByText('Agree');

        act(() => {
            fireEvent.click(agreeButton);
        });

        // since I initialize unseragreement with true this should be called, still it passes, the problem has to be with the waitfor function it
        // obvously doest wait for the click event to complete
        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(onAgree).not.toHaveBeenCalled(); // if not checked the submit function should not be called
        });


    })
})
```

Comment: Well, `waitFor` will wait until the callback does not throw an error. So the test will pass if the assertion is made before the click

Comment: expect(onAgree).not.toHaveBeenCalled() if I change this to expect(onAgree).toHaveBeenCalled() it passes too any idea?